# How to fix 'invalid-argument' error when writing a data frame to CSV using write.csv()?

Tags: r, csv

Faced the problem of an error when writing a data frame to a csv file. The search for reasons was unsuccessful.
About the problem: I write the file with the command `write.csv(df, "df.csv")`
I get an error

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")):
    can't open connection
Optional: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")):
    cannot open file 'df.csv': Invalid argument.
```

The only way I could find is to change the filename - `write.csv(df, "df1.csv")`. This solution seems ugly to me.
Help me figure out how to fix this?

I will add that the path to the folder is correct, trying to specify the file name as a path `(write.csv(df, "C:/Folder /Data/df.csv")` gives the same error.

Comment: Did you check the answer here ?  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211984/r-write-csv-error-cannot-open-file-invalid-argument

Comment: Thank you. I have seen this thread before. But I did not understand what exactly needs to be done to solve the problem. The phrase - "A manual, non-automatic sync of the shared drive forced these problem files into being "Available offline" and eliminated the error" does not give an answer for me. I didn't understand its meaning. I believe by virtue of my experience) Perhaps you can help me? The question is simple - what exactly needs to be done to fix the error? Change the code or some changes in the OS?